# Change numpy value/color red to black

Tags: python, image, numpy, rgb, channel

I want to change the **red value > 100** of image[1] to **RGB(0,0,0)** - image[2] - using Python.

Now:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZhVG.jpg

Target:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcTU0.png

For example, if it's RGB(120,60,90) it should be RGB(0,0,0)

`data = np.array(img)`

`print(data)`

Terminal:

```
[[[10  8  6]
  [10  8  6]
  [10  8  6]
  ...
  [ 8  7  5]
  [ 8  7  5]
  [ 8  7  5]]

 [[10  8  6]
  [10  8  6]
  [10  8  6]
  ...
  [ 8  7  5]
  [ 8  7  5]
  [ 8  7  5]]

 [[10  8  6]
  [10  8  6]
  [10  8  6]
  ...
  [ 8  7  5]
  [ 8  7  5]
  [ 8  7  5]]
```

...

I know that

`data[..., 0]`

is for the red channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're simply trying to change the values in the NumPy array, then just use NumPy's fancy indexing

```
data[data[..., 0] > 100] = np.array([0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: No need to explicitly create an array, you can use `*= 0` and broadcasting takes care of the rest.

Comment: Interestingly `*= 0`  seems to perform pretty terribly. I figured the two would be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
red_channel = data[..., 0]
mask = red_chanel > 100
data[mask] = [0,0,0]
```

I think ... you might have to get a bit fancier

```
data[mask][...,0] = 0 
data[mask][...,1] = 0 
data[mask][...,2] = 0
```

(there is probably an easier way to set it but that should work)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner:

```py
(rgb[..., 0] < 100)[..., np.newaxis] * rgb
```

This also works (haven't tested which is faster):

```py
rgb[rgb[..., 0] > 100] *= 0
```

Here's the result on a random `(3, 5, 3)` array:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> rgb = np.random.randint(0, 255, (3, 5, 3), dtype="uint8")
>>> rgb
array([[[159, 204, 134],
        [208, 224, 176],
        [177,  57,  26],
        [213, 191,  17],
        [ 71, 205, 162]],

       [[124,  94,  64],
        [ 41, 231, 130],
        [ 90, 235, 124],
        [ 18, 237, 101],
        [ 92,  86, 250]],

       [[104, 107, 251],
        [ 27, 247, 214],
        [123, 129,  88],
        [199, 105, 225],
        [ 29, 223, 117]]], dtype=uint8)
>>>
>>> (rgb[..., 0] < 100)[..., np.newaxis] * rgb
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [ 71, 205, 162]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [ 41, 231, 130],
        [ 90, 235, 124],
        [ 18, 237, 101],
        [ 92,  86, 250]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [ 27, 247, 214],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [ 29, 223, 117]]], dtype=uint8)
```

EDIT: I did some very simple benchmarking on a 500x500 pixel "image":

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: rgb = np.random.randint(0, 255, (500, 500, 3), dtype="uint8")

In [3]: rgb_copy = rgb.copy()

In [4]: %timeit rgb_copy[rgb[..., 0] > 100] *= 0
6.63 ms ± 15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [5]: rgb_copy = rgb.copy()

In [6]: %timeit rgb_copy[rgb[..., 0] > 100] = np.array([0, 0, 0])
3.25 ms ± 14.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [7]: rgb_copy = rgb.copy()

In [8]: %timeit new_rgb = rgb * (rgb[..., 0] < 100)[..., np.newaxis]
1.24 ms ± 2.91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

*Pretty* similar results although my first suggestion seems to perform the best in my testing.

Comment: not sure what size images you're dealing with but the gaps start to widen between our solutions as the image size grows. I've only done some very simple speed testing, though. If speed is of concern you may want to consider using mine, or at the very least doing some benchmarking yourself.